# Manipulating tag names and output structure in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have a SQL query that produces one row, with multiple columns from Microsoft SQL Server 2016.

I am trying to produce output in XML format, and can use the SQL XML basic parameters to get variations of:

```
<FirstName>Fred</FirstName>
<LastName>Smith</LastName>
..
..
..
```

What I need is:

```
<Answer name=“FirstName”>
  <value>Fred</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name=“LastName”>
  <value>Smith</value>
</Answer>
..
..
..
```

(I realize this may be an inefficient structure for XML - I didn't design the target!)

Here is the example:

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, FirstName 
VARCHAR(20), LastName VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @tbl (FirstName, LastName) VALUES
('Fred', 'Smith'),
('Anna', 'Polack');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM @tbl FOR XML  PATH('')
```

Produces:

```
<FirstName>Fred</FirstName>
<LastName>Smith</LastName>
<FirstName>Anna</FirstName>
<LastName>Polack</LastName>
```

If I use the following:

```
select STRING_AGG('<Answer name="'+ColKey+'">'+ 
'<value>'+ColValue+'</value></Answer>',' ')
from
(
select  tab.* from @tbl
CROSS APPLY (
VALUES  ('FirstName', FirstName),
('LastName', LastName)
) tab(ColKey, ColValue)
)t
```

then I can get what I need:

```
<Answer name="FirstName"><value>Fred</value></Answer>
<Answer name="LastName"><value>Smith</value></Answer>
<Answer name="FirstName"><value>Anna</value></Answer> 
<Answer name="LastName"><value>Polack</value></Answer>
```

Is there is a more straightforward approach that doesn't require me to explicitly enumerate all the columns?

Thanks in advance.

Yitzhak Kabinsky's SQL #2 does this well.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your RDBMS and its version.

Comment: Also, the desired output is not a **well-formed** XML. It is missing a root element.

Comment: What is your specific RDBMS?  Different SQL systems may potentially have their own unique ways of dealing with XML data (whether input or output)

Comment: Microsoft SQL 2016.  OP edited accordingly.

Comment: The issue is not with the root or header components, but with the resulting tag structure.

Comment: You need to provide all ##1-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **minimal reproducible example** is not provided. Shooting from the hip.

Notable points:

- `CROSS APPLY` is producing a generic XML regardless of the table
  structure.
- XQuery FLWOR expression is composing a precise desired XML output.

Overall, the answer is following the same **minimal reproducible example** pattern. You copy it to SSMS as-is, and it is working.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, FirstName VARCHAR(20), LastName VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @tbl (FirstName, LastName) VALUES
('Fred', 'Smith'),
('Anna', 'Polack');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID
    , x.query('for $x in /root/*
        return <Answer name="{local-name($x)}">
          <value>{data($x)}</value>
        </Answer>') AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(x);
```

**Output**

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID |                                                                         Result                                                                         |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | <Answer name="ID"><value>1</value></Answer><Answer name="FirstName"><value>Fred</value></Answer><Answer name="LastName"><value>Smith</value></Answer>  |
|  2 | <Answer name="ID"><value>2</value></Answer><Answer name="FirstName"><value>Anna</value></Answer><Answer name="LastName"><value>Polack</value></Answer> |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**SQL #2**

```
;WITH rs(x) AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM @tbl
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')
)
SELECT x.query('for $x in /root/*
        return <Answer name="{local-name($x)}">
          <value>{data($x)}</value>
        </Answer>') AS Result 
FROM rs;
```

**Output**

```
<Answer name="ID">
  <value>1</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="FirstName">
  <value>Fred</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="LastName">
  <value>Smith</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="ID">
  <value>2</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="FirstName">
  <value>Anna</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="LastName">
  <value>Polack</value>
</Answer>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  When I try the example, I am getting 'Cannot find either column "x" or the user-defined function or aggregate "x.query", or the name is ambiguous.'  as well as '"t1" has more columns than specified in the columns list?

Comment: The answer is following a **minimal reproducible example** pattern. You copy it to SSMS as-is, run it, and it is working. Please edit your question, and provide all ##1-4 like in my comments under your original question.

Comment: It is not working for me.

Comment: OP edited to give requested components

Comment: I updated the answer with SQL #2. Check it out.

Comment: SQL #2 works great, thank you.  I thought the leading ; may be a typo, but it isn't.  I'm going to edit the OP to reference that solution and also post a second variation of the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as answer.