# Creating dynamic XML tag names for output from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

(This is a follow on to [Manipulating tag names and output structure in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75861339/manipulating-tag-names-and-output-structure-in-sql) which was well answered by Yitzhak Khabinsky)

I am trying to extract data from Microsoft SQL Server 2016 in specific XML formats.  I can get close with standard FOR XML statements, but do not have any experience using XQuery - which I suspect is at the heart of an elegant solution.

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, FirstName 
VARCHAR(20), MiddleName VARCHAR(20), LastName VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @tbl (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName) VALUES
('Fred', 'A.','Smith'),
('Anna', NULL,'Polack');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

select * from @tbl

;WITH rs(x) AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM @tbl
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')
)
SELECT
 x.query('for $x in /root/*
        return <Answer name="{local-name($x)}">
          <value>{data($x)}</value>
        </Answer>') AS Result 
FROM rs
```

Produces the following:

```
<Answer name="ID">
  <value>1</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="FirstName">
  <value>Fred</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="MiddleName">
  <value>A.</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="LastName">
  <value>Smith</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="ID">
  <value>2</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="FirstName">
  <value>Anna</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="LastName">
  <value>Polack</value>
</Answer>
```

I would like to get more explicit enumeration of the output like the following:

```
<Answer name="ID_1">
  <value>1</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="FirstName_1">
  <value>Fred</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="MiddleName_1">
  <value>A.</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="LastName_1">
  <value>Smith</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="ID_2">
  <value>2</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="FirstName_2">
  <value>Anna</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="LastName_2">
  <value>Polack</value>
</Answer>
```

I can hack it by using:

```
select STRING_AGG('<Answer name="'+ColKey+'">'+ 
'<value>'+ColValue+'</value></Answer>',' ')
from
(
select  tab.* from @tbl
CROSS APPLY (
VALUES  ('FirstName_'+cast(ID as varchar), FirstName),
('LastName_'+cast(ID as varchar), LastName)
) tab(ColKey, ColValue)
)t
```

But I'm sure there is a more elegant way using XQuery

Comment: FYI, [so] isnt a place to ask "in parts"; each question should be complete in it's own merit. You should really provide a better title here than; it reads like we're going to need to be able to address*both* posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for string_agg()

**Example**

```
Select  [Answer/@name] = concat('ID','_',id)
       ,[Answer/value] = id
       ,null
       ,[Answer/@name] = concat('FirstName','_',id)
       ,[Answer/value] = FirstName
       ,null
       ,[Answer/@name] = concat('MiddleName','_',id)
       ,[Answer/value] = MiddleName
       ,null
       ,[Answer/@name] = concat('LastName','_',id)
       ,[Answer/value] = LastName
 From   @tbl
 For xml path('')
```

**Results**

```
<Answer name="ID_1">
  <value>1</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="FirstName_1">
  <value>Fred</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="MiddleName_1">
  <value>A.</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="LastName_1">
  <value>Smith</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="ID_2">
  <value>2</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="FirstName_2">
  <value>Anna</value>
</Answer>
<Answer name="MiddleName_2" />
<Answer name="LastName_2">
  <value>Polack</value>
</Answer>
```

**UPDATE:**  For Many columns.  Since you have `string_agg()`... I can assume you've got `OPENJSON`.

**Example**

```
Select [Answer/@name] = concat([key],'_',A.ID)
      ,[Answer/value] = B.value
 From  @tbl A
  Cross Apply  (
                 Select [Key]
                       ,Value
                 From OpenJson(  (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )  ) 
              ) B
 For xml path('')
```

Comment: Thanks, John.  However my ultimate table has many columns, so I was hoping for a way to avoid having to specifically name each one.  With your approach, is there a way to avoid the nulls? (e.g. Middlename_2)?

Comment: Worth mentioning.  Give me a minute

Comment: Thank you, John.  Very clear - marked as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` in the XQuery to add the `ID` value onto it.

You just need to break out the first generated XML in two levels

```sql
WITH rs(x) AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @tbl
    FOR XML PATH('row'), TYPE
)
SELECT
 x.query('for $x in /row
          for $y in $x/*
        return <Answer name="{concat(local-name($y), "_", ($x/ID/text())[1])}">
          <value>{data($y)}</value>
        </Answer>') AS Result 
FROM rs;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/uO_8otbF)